# Running node with php shell_exec doesn't work when logging off

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Hello I have a weird problem (at least for me :P). The part of my code:

```
shell_exec('node script.tjs > /dev/null 2>&1 &')
```

I tried solving this by adding a `nohup` before but still no luck.
The code runs via supervisor and when I'm logged in (via ssh) the script works like a charm but the moment I log off - it stops.
All other code related stuff works fine (the given script is part of the process) but this one doesn't execute.

I have no idea what happened here and I would appreciate your help :)